# How to run a second process with dependency to a running process using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I want to do an automation for 2 processes using shell script.
I have 2 programs, *a* is a workload, *b* is a CPU profiler to profile the cpu when *a* is running.

Previously, I run these programs manually, by opening 2 terminals. First, run *a* in the first terminal, then in another terminal, I get the process ID of *a*, and finally run `./b [pid-of-a]`. This has caused me to miss the profiling of the first few seconds of process *a*.

I tried:

```sh
./a &
pid=$! & 
./b pid
```

But it does not work the way I wanted. It runs *b* first and returns an error because the PID of *a* does not exist. I can't use `&&` as well because it will wait *a* to finish first before *b* starts which is not the way I want.

What modification should I do to my code regarding such dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Don't set `pid` in the background, and remember to put a `$` when you want to expand it:

```
./a & 
pid=$!
./b "$pid"
```

Or just

```
./a &  
./b $!
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a bash script which will check for ProcessA using pgrep and gets its pid

```html
#!/bin/sh

while true
do
    pid=`pgrep -f processA`
    if [ ! -z $pid ]
    then
        ./processB $pid
        break
    fi
done
```